# Recurring appointments during a given period, MAPI way

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

When you query EWS or Outlook API for appointments restricted by some period for recurring ones you get fake instances. Exchange keeps only the main instance with recurrence pattern and exceptions list, and if one have to use MAPI one should "unpack"  this solo appointment to get occurences by hand. That's not the problem ) The real pain I still cannot cure is how to get main appointments which reside outside of given period but their occurences are inside, I want to evade getting all recurring appointments (or even at some reasonable distance from given period for example a year to the left), "unpacking" and checking for ocurrences which are between our dates.

The current action sequence:

- IMAPITable.Restrict on dates
- .SetColumns
- .QueryRows

  Do MAPI interfaces have some methods or parameters which allow to achive my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Here http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/redemption-recurring-activities-t2964080.html I've found detailed answer: pidLidClipStart and pidLidClipEnd instead of PR_START/END_DATE filtering.